# JSON API Response matching using karate

Tags: karate

I need to match a GET response of an api using karate. 
Although i am able to do it using individual matching but it is becoming a very huge pile of code. I am looking to reduce the lines of code. PFB the working way of response matching.

GET API RESPONSE is

```
{
"address": {
    "city": "Warsaw",
    "street": "1212 Main St",
    "postalCode": "22-333"
},
"dateOfBirth": "1996-09-08T00:00:00+0000",
"email": "auth@mail.com",
"id": "123456",
"givenName": "Clap",
"mobilePhone": "23456778787",
"familyName": "Customer"
}
```

I am able to manage the Validation using the below

```
And match header vary == 'origin' 
And match header Content-Type == 'application/json; charset=utf-8' 
And match header access-control-expose-headers == 'WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization' 
And match header cache-control == 'no-cache' 
And match header accept-ranges == 'bytes' 
And match header Content-Length == '225' 

And match $.dateOfBirth == '1996-09-08T00:00:00+0000' 
And match $.email == 'auth@mail.com' 
And match $.id == '123456' 
And match $.givenName == 'Clap' 
And match $.mobilePhone == '23456778787' 
And match $.familyName == 'Customer' 

And match response.address.city contains 'Warsaw' 
And match response.address.street contains '1212 Main St' 
And match response.address.postalCode contains '22-333'
```

I have tried some of the approaches given but it does not help in validation.

Comment: @Nilesh : There is a detailed explanation on Github for assertions ( https://github.com/intuit/karate#set-multiple ) But if you want a more detailed ( step by step ) code then I suggest you accept the previous answer of yours :P
FYI - Peter is the creator of Karate :)

Comment: i have marked the previous query as answered ;)  Also, i know peter has created it, I am just trying of with Karate to see if we can fit it in our scheme of things. It would be a humble request to add create some videos of the basic items of karate. once a candidate is through doing that he/she can extend it by going through the github documentation and the demo code checked in.

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs. You can match response JSON in a single line:

```
* match response ==
"""
{
"address": {
    "city": "Warsaw",
    "street": "1212 Main St",
    "postalCode": "22-333"
},
"dateOfBirth": "1996-09-08T00:00:00+0000",
"email": "auth@mail.com",
"id": "123456",
"givenName": "Clap",
"mobilePhone": "23456778787",
"familyName": "Customer"
}
"""
```

Normally you don't need to focus on the headers, because they tend to change depending on the type of server, os, etc. Maybe some tests can do what you are doing but not all.